# Jquery to load a link content on a div and keep refreshing same div ever 5 secound with same link content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I have this scrip to load a href into a div but im trying to build a live chat and I also need to keep refeshing the targe div with the href info.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.msg_history').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 linkLoad($(this).attr('href'));
 });

function linkLoad(hre){
$('.msg_history').load(hre, function(){
   setTimeout(linkLoad(hre), 5000);
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Reshmin, It does work refreshing, but when I click on more then one link its trying to load into the div every link a had clicked.